# CodeIgniter Controllers and AJAX

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns, codeigniter

**EDIT: Previous title, because no one was reading the question:** "If I'm making AJAX calls in an MVC framework, is it common to have 'getter' controller methods over the model?"

It's all in the title: If I want to make an AJAX call to delete a user, that DB code clearly lives in the model `$this->userModel->delete($id)`.

If I'm making all of the CRUD calls via AJAX, do I just have passthrough controller methods to expose those model calls to a URL?

```
function delete($id) {
    $this->userModel->delete($id);
}
```

etc? This seems silly, but it also makes sense... but it also makes me feel like I'm missing something. Is this the most common pattern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes down to Ajax under the MVC Framework I usually tend to have each function with a specified keyword such as fetch / set.
something like this

```
class Users extends Controller
{
    public function Fetch($id){}
    public function Create(){}
    public function Update($id){}
    public function Remove($id){}
}
```

To answer your question: **yes**

The task of the controller is the decision maker, so that you would perform authentication checks etc within the controller for security purposes.

Think of it this way, you would not use the same controller for changing records in your administration as you would within your users front-end, but you would use the same models.

the models should be used in more places than just the front end, so you would not place a session check, input validation in the model methods as you would perform different checks depending on the location the action is taking place.

Your frontend controller would have something along the lines of:

```
public function Fetch($id)
{
    if($this->session->get_userdata("auth_level") & USER_AUTH_LEVEL_READ)
    {
        //Show data
    }
}
```

where as your administration would have:

```
public function Fetch($id)
{
    if($this->session->get_userdata("auth_level") & IS_ADMINISTRATOR)
    {
        //Show data
    }
}
```

if you place the very same check in your models then you would have generate several models that would do return the same data regardless of the location.

Comment: OK, perfect, thanks for the sanity check. I also have 'higher level' controller methods around, many of which USE several of those 'utility' methods, but it seems they still ought to be split off for individual access by XHR calls.